# How to install drivers for N300 usb adapter?

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, usb, adapter

I have tried bits and pieces of EVERYTHING. I have ZERO clue what I am doing and am not sure what I have done so far. I need help with downloading the drivers and setting up my N300 for Ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: What is the output of the wireless info script from [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)?

Comment: Can you explain what that is and how I do that? I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: The top answer explains it pretty clearly. Open a Terminal somehow (possibly using Ctrl+Alt+T), then do `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info`, followed by `chmod +x wireless-info`, and, finally, `./wireless-info
`. This should create a file called `wireless-info.txt`. We need the contents of that text file, so you can paste it here or in a pastebin.

Comment: It says "resolving github.com (github.com) ... failed: Temporary failure in name resolution. wget: unable to resolve host address 'github.com' after the first command

Comment: The `wget` requires an internet connection. Is the computer on which you are executing these commands connected to the internet?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/7D9UfXbf think I did this right?

Comment: Or maybe this way http://pastebin.com/9bu6ekwS

Comment: You can trust chili555 on this ;)

Answer (score 4):

I regret that there is no way to get your `0846:9020` device reliably working. In fact, I actually own one and have tried many times and in many ways to get it to work properly. This thread explains the process and details the several failures: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2264020

I suggest that you look instead for any one of several fully supported devices. Although there are many others, I have and can recommend the TP-Link TL-WN722N.

Comment: Dang it. Dont want to have to buy stuff. Thats why I got Ubuntu in the first place and not windows :P Thanks though!